# C# Windows Form Program on ARM Linux based on QT with MONO

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, embedded-linux

Command Link Programme is Ok.

When I run Windows Form Program, Error message shows:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libX11.so
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11:XInitThreads ()
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And My arm Linux's GUI is based on QT.

What shoud I do?

Build X11 library or build GTK#?

My thought isnot clear now. Could you give me some guides and Reference materials?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have X11 on the platform. Is it using a specialised implementation of Qt to render to a framebuffer or something?

Comment: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Matrix_Gui_Version_1

Comment: It is Based on this platform.

Comment: That's the tutorial for some sort of HTML-based GUI framework.

Comment: Matrix v2 : Server based and runs using Javascript and PHP. Runs both locally on the target and remotely on any modern browser connected to a LAN.

Comment: So you're trying to run a X11-based app on a platform that uses a web server for its UI? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: You mean I should try to build a full X11 GUI？

Comment: As the exception message indicates, you might try to port X11 to this system. Otherwise, you will have to abandon the WinForms UI and completely migrated to the UI supported by the Linux system you use, such as Qt (via Qyoto, http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Mar-16.html). However, whether you can do that depends heavily on how much the underlying Linux system can offer.

Comment: how about GTK#? Is it usefull?

Comment: It seems like Gtk2 *can* be built against the framebuffer: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-directfb.html . That said, you might have to do that yourself for your platform if it doesn't provide a build for you. you'll still have to build GTK# against that Gtk2 version. I also don't quite know how framebuffers work, chances are that in the absence of X11 your application will just take over the entire display of the device instead of opening windows on it. (Or it might not. I really have no idea.)

Comment: You might also be able to do something similar with the Qt that's provided by your Linux already, but seems like Qt Embedded (which supports a framebuffer and is probably what that Linux uses) is in some way a different entity than regular Qt, which is what binding developers probably target. It might work, or it might not, but don't expect much guidance on how to do it to be available. Generally speaking you're likely to be making life very hard on yourself by not just using whatever "native" APIs are already available on the embedded platform. (Qt, or that Matrix thing.)

Comment: And while I'm suggesting insane options, it seems like Gtk3 can now render to HTML5: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html. At the very least this would get rid of a dependency on graphics rendering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now, I have a clear thinking in mind and firstly I will try to build X11. If it doesnot work, I will try GTK# and GTK2 or even GTK3.